# How to add multiple variables in .val() jquery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am adding data using AJAX then appending that data in dropdown, after that I am using `.val().trigger()` jQuery function to get that newly added data on the top of drop down by passing multiple variables in .val() function; val function is accepting one variable and working fine but I want to add multiple variables in val() function.

**JS CODE**

```
success: function(data) {
  toastr['success']("<?php echo lang('add'); ?>", "Customer Device Added");
  setTimeout(function() {
    const obj = JSON.parse(data);
    // console.log(data)
    // console.log(obj)
    jQuery('#customer_device').append('<option value="' + obj[0].device_brand + ' ' + obj[0].device_model + ' ' + obj[0].device_imei + '">' + obj[0].device_brand + ' ' + obj[0].device_model + ' ' + obj[0].device_imei + '</option>');
    jQuery('#customer_device').val(obj[0].device_brand).trigger("change");
    $('#customer_device_modal').modal('hide');
  }, 500);
}
```

Here I am appending these data:

```
obj[0].device_brand, obj[0].device_model, obj[0].device_imei
```

I want to trigger these all variables in .val() function to get these in dropdown at top; as I am getting one variable in val function.  Thank you

Comment: The value isn't `obj[0].device_brand` it's `obj[0].device_brand+' '+obj[0].device_model+'  '+obj[0].device_imei` so you need to use that in the `.val()` call.

Comment: Add `selected` when you build your option and forget about setting it via .`val()` - ie `jQuery('#customer_device').append('<option selected value=...`

Comment: O Man, where are you since 2 days, Thank you, thank you so so much; Both methods working perfectly; Thanks alot again.